# Does a HTTP response indicate the address of the receiver or something similar?

Tags: http, web

A HTTP request indicates the resource on the server by the URL in the start line and the HOST header.

Does a HTTP response indicate the address of the receiver or something similar?
If not, why is it not necessary?

Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Internet protocols are layered.

HTTP requests are wrapped in TCP packages, which are wrapped in IP.

The outside IP packet contains information about who is the receipient and who is the sender of a message. Based on this information a TCP/IP service knows where to send the message back to.

The `Host` header was actually a later addition to HTTP. It wasn't really needed before because it was safer to assume that a single ip address would have a single HTTP service. The Host header was added because people needed many different domains to be served from a smaller set of ip addresses and send different responses based on what the domain was.

Without the `Host` header it wouldn't have been possible to know which domain the user wanted because the ip packet only encodes the ip address, not which domain was used to find the ip.